# c:forEach returning an incorrect format for domain model

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

Values that I am passing to the list has id=1, Description=Java.

Now I am passing the list to JSP using

```
<select name='position_id'>
      <c:forEach var="position_id" items="${positionList}">
            <option value="${position_id}">${position_id.description}</option>
      </c:forEach>
</select>
```

But the values I am getting are of the form: **position {0, position{1, Java}}**

But I need them in the form **position{1, Java}**

The Position table has

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;
```

Can someone help me out with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Change

`<option value="${position_id}">${position_id.description}</option>`

to

`<option value="${position_id.description}">${position_id.description}</option>`

You will start getting the description as the value. But I think you should be extracting the ID as the value and display description as text. So in my opinion, you should do the following:

`<option value="${position_id.id}">${position_id.description}</option>`